# Default MVC Header Missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a newly-created ASP.net MVC application, the header isn't displaying properly. I assumed this was due to a missing CSS file, but the Console shows nothing. I've tried clearing the cache and refreshing with no luck. Also, this site does not Require SSL so it doesn't have to do with some content being served over HTTP vs. HTTPS.

[image]

Comment: Have you made any change to CSS file?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I have not.

Comment: It looks like template was generated on bootstrap 3.3.7 and then changed bootstrap file reference to bootstrap 4.x..

Comment: @TanvirArjel You were correct - I forgot that I had updated all the packages. Thank you!